# Maximum value of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)= \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{(x^2-x)^2+y^4} \,dy, $$
and $x \in [0,1].$ What is the maximum value of $f(x)?$ At the endpoints $f$ is equal to $0$ and $1/3$ respectively. I tried to find the stationary points from $f'(x)=0$ using the Leibniz integral rule and concluded that on the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ the only stationary point is $0$. But I got stuck with the case $x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Could someone help me with the latter case or provide some better methods? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take a break from grading my calculus exams and make a silly mistake like that. How embarrasing. Thanks for the correction @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: @James Haha it‘s all good, happy correcting and merry Christmas 

Comment: A numerical test seems to show that $f$ increases monotonically. The maximum would be $1/3$ at $x=1$. Actually, even $f(x)/x$ seems to be increasing.

Comment: Also: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821870/maximizing-int-0y-sqrtx4y-y22-dx), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894170/find-the-maximum-value-of-an-integral), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386453/find-the-maximum-value-of-72-int-limits-0y-sqrtx4y-y22dx)